# Open source motion-capture software

Tags: simulation, tracking, 3d-modelling

Is there any open source software to map points on the human body to a simulated 3D model? Something like they do in some movies to map the movement of actors onto 3D models. What do they use? Are there any open initiatives for a wider audience in this domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Open Source Motion Capture Software Project from UFMG, in Brasil, which can be downloaded here https://github.com/davidflam/OpenMoCap

Comment: I cannot open the link. Is there another link ?

Comment: This link is dead again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for (open source) motion capture software. I don't know of any dedicated mocap software that's open source, however.

My guess: any solution will probably involve Blender. I haven't used Blender myself, but it's open source, so there's lots of potential. I did come across a few promising links (Google "blender motion capture"):

- [Blender wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Tutorials/Animation/Advanced/MoCap)
- [Open world film](http://openworldfilm.com/blogs/cj/2009/03/20/157/comment-page-1/)
- [Using pre-existing mocap data](http://feeblemind.tuxfamily.org/dotclear/index.php/2007/08/17/94-around-600-mocapad-data-sets-on-mocapdatacom)

Blender does have the ability to import motion capture (`.bvh`) files; I'm not sure if it can create them as well.

My guess is that movie studios use expensive and/or privately developed software,  like [Optitrack](http://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/).